# How to fix "Failed to mount root filesystem - failed to open /dev/console" in RedHat after Cloning Disk

Tags: linux, rhel, grub, boot-loader, clonezilla

After cloning my HDD by Norton Ghost to a new one, I moved the new disk to new PC (with different hardware).
In the new PC , I see this message at boot, as you see in this screenshot:

[image]
What exactly is this message supposed to tell me, and how can i fix that?
I also tested some grub solutions like this page : 
https://kb.acronis.com/content/1686

Thanks

Comment: After  you cloned the drive, did you do a grub-install on the boot partition? This is necessary sometimes when disk geometries are different. I think if this were the problem, you wouldn't have gotten as far as you did. But I have trouble reconciling Murphy's answer with something as vanilla as the console ... unless the initrd image isn't properly mapped (logical blocks to physical ones)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the device nodes of the new drive on the new system don't match the old ones you cloned with the partition(s). Start a rescue system (Knoppix or any other live system), determine which node in `/dev` is used for which partition, mount the root partition and adjust `<mountpoint>/etc/fstab` and your bootloader configuration (probably in `<mountpoint>/boot`, or on the boot partition if you have one).

If the device nodes/partition scheme seems to be identical, perhaps you are missing some basic nodes in `<mountpoint>/dev` that are needed before *devtmpfs* is mounted to `/dev`; create them from the rescue system, e. g.

```
mknod <mountpoint>/dev/console c 5 1
```

You should be able to determine the node type/IDs and their permissions from `/dev` of the rescue system. I'm not totally sure, but I think `/dev/null` and one or two others are necessary, too, but that may vary with each distribution.

Comment: I changed Motherboard and afetr that kernel started but holds on this error http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yax9G.jpg